# Getting server responded with a status of 500 on Return from Controller GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

hi ive been doing a simple search with ajax at mvc. im a bit puzzled by this error since the ajax can communicate with the Controller on ajax call but when the controller returns a value to the JS it gives me the error500

here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'SearchCustomer',
        data: { 'name': name, 'id': customerId },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $(data).each(function () {

            });
        }
    });
```

then my controller

```
 public JsonResult SearchCustomer(string name, string id)
        {

            var customers = tr.SearchCustomers(name, id);
            return new JsonResult() { Data = customers, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

        }
```

-ive been to many solutions already before asking this question also tried them but amazingly none did work.. so HELP !! :P cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get rid of the `contentType` setting because you are not sending JSON. Also the url to your controller action doesn't look quite valid. If you are using the default routing it should normally look like `{controller}/{action}`. I would recommend you using an Url helper to generate it.

Also in your controller action you've used the `Data` property to send the results, so that's what you should use in your success callback to loop through:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SearchCustomer")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { 'name': name, 'id': customerId },
    success: function (result) {
        $(result.Data).each(function () {

        });
    }
});
```

Another thing you should be looking for is the model that you are sending to the view from your controller action:

```
var customers = tr.SearchCustomers(name, id);
```

It is not clear what is the type of this customers collection is but you should make sure that it is JSON serializable. This means that the `Customer` model should not contain any circular references i nits object graph. If it does you will have to exclude them, ideally by using a view model and sending only the properties that are needed to your view.

Comment: thanks by using a view model it worked like a charm! as you suspected customers was not JSON serializable that's why ive been getting errors! thanks alot Darin

Comment: one more thing ive noticed that my url is not in the correct Controller/Method form but if i had it in that form the url goes Like
Controller/Controller/Method that's why i had to remove Controller- frankly i dont know why it happens like that